# How can I retrieve a numerical value depending on which radioButton is clicked in this scenario?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prompts);


    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioGroup.clearCheck();


    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if(null!=rb && checkedId > -1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Currently the toast will show whatever text is associated with the specific button.  I have a stack of 6 buttons and would like instead to retrive an integer from 0-5 depending on which button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int btnCheck;
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
  switch(checkedId){
    case R.id.radio1:
                btnCheck=0;
                break;
    case R.id.radio2:
                btnCheck=1;
                break;
    case R.id.radio2:
                btnCheck=2;
                break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it working with your help :)